# What happens if we create objects within a loop?

Tags: c++

My question is, "What happens if we create objects within a loop?"

Example:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        Foo* bar = new Foo(i); //here Foo(i) is a parameterized constructor
    }
```

and how to delete them?

Comment: better use a smart pointer for memory management

Comment: @FatGiant I am just asking this for some knowledge. What happens if I do this ?

Comment: We really need to know more about what you're trying to do tbh.

Comment: This makes no sense. Why would you do this? Is there a problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you wrote, you are creating a new object on the free store (the heap) at every iteration. You may want either to destroy the object at the end of the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
{
    Foo* bar = new Foo(i); //here Foo(i) is a parameterized constructor
    // do stuff...
    delete bar;
}
```

or collect pointers in a container and destroy it later:

```
std::vector<Foo*> v;
for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
{
    Foo* bar = new Foo(i); //here Foo(i) is a parameterized constructor
    v.push_back(bar);
}
// do stuff...
for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
{
    delete v[i];
}
```

Comment: Wow that was really helpful. By the way, what happens if I do not delete objects at the end of each iteration ?

Comment: You leak memory if you don't delete them.

Answer (score 3):

Memory leaks.

First iteration a `bar` object will be created and allocated the memory its needed. The next iteration (and all) the previous reference of `bar` will be lost and a new memory reference will be allocated. So you can not find the previously created `bar`.

As all of the previous reference of `bar` is lost, you cannot `delete` or `free` those memory and hence, [Memory Leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

Answer (score 3):

> What happens if we create objects within a loop [like this]?

Memory leaks.

There's no way to delete them if `bar` goes out of scope (as it does, at the end of the loop body).

> how to delete them?

You need the address of the objects to be able to delete them. If you need to delete them outside the loop, you have to store their addresses outside the loop:

```
std::vector<Foo*> fooPointers;
fooPointers.reserve(iterations);

for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
{
    Foo* bar = new Foo(i);
    fooPointers.push_back(bar);
}

for (Foo* p : fooPointers)
{
    delete p;
}
```

**A better solution** however, would be (as mentioned by @[FatGiant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1400995/fatgiant)) to use **smart pointers** instead of dumb pointers to automagically prevent any memory leaks:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> fooPointers;
fooPointers.reserve(iterations);

for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
{
    fooPointers.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Foo>(new Foo(i)));
    Foo& bar = *fooPointers.back();
}

fooPointers.clear(); // calls delete on all Foos, note that this step is optional
```

Comment: Memory leaks can still happen with smart pointers, if exceptions are thrown before memory has been freed